# Apply data annotation validation but ignore formatting

Tags: jquery, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an MVC form which allows the user to enter a number of up to 10 digits.

This is displayed on the form with some formatting - 1000000000 would appear as 10,000,000.00.

These fields need to be validated and the regular expressions that are used for the annotations do not take formatting into account.

```
MyView.cshtml
@HtmlTextBoxFor(t => t.Value, "{0:C0}");

MyClass
{
    [RegularExpression("^(-)?\d{1,10}$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a number of up to 10 digits")]
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

If I want to validate this as a 10 digit number, allowing for a particular display format - do I have to update all of the regular expressions to allow commas and the like, or is there something clever that I can do to ignore the formatting, but apply the validation against the underlying value only?

I am using the out of the box MVC Data Annotations and the jQuery.unobtrusive library.

Comment: `RegularExpression` is for string, not double. If this Value is not supposed to be used in any calculations, just use string instead. If not, do not use `RegularExpression`.

Comment: By the way, why do you have file extensions at the end of your class name?

Comment: Sorry, typo - removed

Comment: You edits make even less sense - you cant use `@Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.Value, "{0:C0}");` if property `Value` is a `string` You can only format numeric and DateTime` types